NGINX returns 403 for jenkins reverse proxy
I am receiving 403 from NGINX server while accessing the Jenkins master server.
Please note: following setup is a docker swarm cluster.
Here is the docker-compose setup:
version: "3.8"

services:

  master:
    image: jenkins/jenkins:lts-alpine
    user: root
    environment:
      TZ: "Europe/Paris"
    networks:
      - network
    volumes:
      - master_data:/var/jenkins_home

  nginx:
    image: nginx:latest
    networks:
      - network
    configs:
      - source: NGINX_CONFIG
        target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 9000:8080

networks:
  network:
    driver: overlay
    attachable: true

volumes:
  master_data:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      type: none
      o: bine
      device: /var/data/jenkins/master

configs:
  NGINX_CONFIG:
    file: nginx.conf
    name: NGINX_CONFIG

Here is the NGINX config file:
events { worker_connections 1024; }

http {
    include mime.types;
    resolver 127.0.0.11 valid=30s;
    set_real_ip_from  10.0.0.0/8;
    set_real_ip_from  172.16.0.0/12;
    set_real_ip_from  192.168.0.0/16;
    real_ip_header    X-Forwarded-For;
    proxy_connect_timeout 300s;
    proxy_read_timeout 300s;

    server {
        listen              80;
        server_name         jenkins.example.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://master:8080;
            proxy_redirect off;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;

            proxy_set_header    Upgrade             $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    Connection          "upgrade";

            proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
            proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header    X-XSRF-TOKEN        $http_x_xsrf_token;
            proxy_cache_bypass                      $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        }
    }
}

I am unable to identify any errors in the browser or nginx logs that would prevent me from proceeding. I have not found any relevant information in the Jenkins master logs either. Any guidance you can provide would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Have you tried accessing jenkins directly, without the reverse proxy? By the way where did you get this nginx config? Jenkins has a known working one here
